# Custom added ajax pagination not working

Tags: magento2, ajax, pagination

I have added an ajax pagination in a custom module collection. I have a total of 50 items in the collection and the limit per page is 5; that should show total page of 10.

Instead, it is showing only 5 pages, it is not showing the next page Link either and there is no active clickable page link.

When I click on 5 (number page) or Next arrow, it should display next page like `6 7 8` etc but it does not

I have followed the File path Below to implement This pagination.

**Step 1: Block file code.**

File path: **app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Test.php**

```
public function getPagerHtml()
{
    if ($this->getLayout()->getBlock('test.page.pager')) {
        $this->pager = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('test.page.pager');

        return $this->pager->toHtml();
    }

    if (!$this->pager) {
        $this->pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            Pager::class,
            'test.page.pager'
        );

        if ($this->pager) {
            $this->pager->setUseContainer(
                false
            )->setShowPerPage(
                false
            )->setShowAmounts(
                false
            )->setFrameLength(
                $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                    'design/pagination/pagination_frame',
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                )
            )->setJump(
                $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                    'design/pagination/pagination_frame_skip',
                    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
                )
            )->setLimit(5)->setCollection(
                $this->getLocationCollection()
            );

            return $this->pager->toHtml();
        }
    }

    return '';
}

public function getLocationCollection()
{
    $pageNumber = (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('p') ? (int)$this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;
    if (!$this->itemCollection) {
        $this->itemCollection = $this->itemCollectionFactory->create();
    }
    $this->itemCollection->setCurPage($pageNumber);
    $this->itemCollection->setPageSize(5);

    return $this->itemCollection;
}

protected function _prepareLayout()
{     
      
    $this->getPagerHtml();

    if ($this->pager && !$this->pager->isFirstPage()) {
        $this->addPrevNext(
            $this->getUrl('testpage/index/ajax', ['p' => $this->pager->getCurrentPage() - 1]),
            ['rel' => 'prev']
        );
    }

    if ($this->pager && $this->pager->getCurrentPage() < $this->pager->getLastPageNum()) {
        $this->addPrevNext(
            $this->getUrl('testpage/index/ajax', ['p' => $this->pager->getCurrentPage() + 1]),
            ['rel' => 'next']
        );
    }    

    return parent::_prepareLayout();
}

 /**
 * Add prev/next pages
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @param array $attributes
 *
 */
private function addPrevNext($url, $attributes)
{
    $this->pageConfig->addRemotePageAsset(
        $url,
        'link_rel',
        ['attributes' => $attributes]
    );
}
```

**Step 2: Controller file.**

File path: **app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Index/Ajax.php**

```
public function execute()
{
    $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();

    if(isset($params['pageNo'])){
        $pageNo = $params['pageNo'];
    }else{
        $pageNo = 1;
    }

    $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()
                ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
                ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
                ->setPageSize(5) 
                ->setCurPage($pageNo); 

    $data = $this->prepareData($collection->getData());
    $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
    $resultJson->setData($data);
    return $resultJson;
}
```

**Step 3: Template file.**

File path: **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/pagetest.phtml**

```
<?php  if ($pager = $block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
    <div class="testpage-pager-container"><?= /** @escapeNotVerified */ $pager; ?></div>
<?php endif;  ?>
```

**Step 4: JS file code.**

File path: **app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/testpage.js**

```
$(".testpage-pager-container li a").live('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var pagignationUrl= $(this).attr('href'); 
    var pageSplit = pagignationUrl.split('/');
    var pageNo = pageSplit[pageSplit.length - 2];  
    $.ajax({
        url : self.options.ajaxUrl,
        type: self.options.method,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {pageNo: pageNo},
        showLoader: true,
        beforeSend: function() {
        },
        success : function(res) {  
           $('#items-list').html(res);
        },
        error : function(request,error)
        {
            alert("Error");
        }
    });    
});
```

[image]

Comment: The problem seems to be in your block "app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Test.php", please debug that carefully.  For example, the code "->setLimit(5)" in function getPagerHtml should be restricting pagination to 5

Comment: It is much easier to do an ajax call to your current url with parameters &p={{desired page number}}&current_categoryid={{current category id}} and replace your container of the whole product list with the product list container in the response.

Comment: @Ravinder First of all I appreciate your help. I have checked as per your suggestion in the block to change ->setLimit(10) but not works.

Comment: @CompactCode I have pass the the url and pageNo in ajax call and replace html as well. I have issue in when store have 55 records and limit is 5 then page will 11 and first is showing 1 2 3 4 5 page after click on 5 number of page then it there should be displacy next page like 6 7 8 But not display 6 7 8 page.

Comment: @KirtiNariya in that case, you need to debug the call $this->pager->toHtml(). Debugging it down will let you know why this only prints 5 pagination

Comment: @Ravinder I have debug as per your suggestion $this->pager->toHtml()
 but no luck.

Comment: If you have a demo link, send it please!

Comment: @m4n0 Actullay custom module in local no demo link available.

Comment: @KirtiNariya issue solved or it still exist?

Comment: @Chikku Not solved. It still exist. Can you share your solution.

Comment: check console for error and kindly please share?

Comment: Will you share your code or tell me what's this " test.page.pager " in or any link which have created the same. I have needed the likewise same too but didn't know how to started @KirtiNariya

Comment: @Prits I have shared code in my question and test.page.pager is just class name.

Comment: will u tell me what should i pass in " $this->pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            Pager::class,
            'test.page.pager'
        ); " this @KirtiNariya

Comment: @KirtiNariya, How can I test your code ? I think issue with `->setPageSize(5)` from controller. what happen if you set it 10 ?

Comment: @Pawan If set `->setPageSize(10)` then it will comes 10 records per page.

Comment: Hi @KirtiNariya i cant reproduce your issue

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this once and let know the result

```
public function execute()
    {
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    
        if(isset($params['pageNo'])){
            $pageNo = $params['pageNo'];
        }else{
            $pageNo = 1;
        }
    
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
                    ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
                    ->setPageSize(5) 
                    ->setCurPage(1); 
    
        $data = $this->prepareData($collection->getData());
        $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $resultJson->setData($data);
        return $resultJson;
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou @Chikku but not working. I have checked in console there is no any error.

Comment: still getting same pagination?

Comment: Yes. still getting the same pagination and same issue occurs.

Comment: am trying it on my local and will update the ans here if i got success

Comment: i think this line ->setCurPage(1);  is not taking any effect because you have called $pageNo in this

Comment: @Pramod Hello, can you share your full code?

Comment: @KirtiNariya Please check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/358193/82670

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This Code**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName**

**registration.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'VendoreName_ModuleName',
    __DIR__
);
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!--
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendoreName_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.0" >
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**db_schema.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */
-->
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="custom_data" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Custom Data">
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="id" padding="6" unsigned="false" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="name" nullable="false" length="25" comment="Name"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="email" nullable="false" length="25" comment="Email"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="description" nullable="false" length="255" comment="Descrition"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
</schema>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc/frontend**

**routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!--
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="custom" frontName="custom">
            <module name="VendoreName_ModuleName"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model**

**CustomData.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model;

use Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel;
use VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomData as CustomDataResourceModel;

class CustomData extends AbstractModel
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(CustomDataResourceModel::class);
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model/ResourceModel**

**CustomData.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

class CustomData extends AbstractDb
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('custom_data', 'id');
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model/ResourceModel/CustomData**

**Collection.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomData;

use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\CustomData as CustomDataModel;
use VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomData as CustomDataResourceModel;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init(
            CustomDataModel::class,
            CustomDataResourceModel::class
        );
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Controller/Index**

**Index.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Custom Pagination'));
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout**

**custom_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="customer_account"/>
     <head>
        <script src="VendoreName_ModuleName::js/ajax_pagination.js" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Pager" name="custom.ajax.pagination" template="VendoreName_ModuleName::pager.phtml" cacheable="false" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block**

**Pager.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Pager extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\CustomData
     */
    protected $customFactory;

    /**
     * @var \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomData\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $customdataCollection;

    /**
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\CustomData $customFactory
     * @param \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomData\CollectionFactory $customdataCollection
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\CustomData $customFactory,
        \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\ResourceModel\CustomData\CollectionFactory $customdataCollection,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->customFactory = $customFactory;
        $this->customdataCollection = $customdataCollection;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->pageConfig->getTitle()->set(__('My Custom Pagination'));
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $page_size = $this->getPagerCount();
        $page_data = $this->getCustomData();
        if ($this->getCustomData()) {
            $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                \VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\CustomPager::class,
                'custom.pager'
            )
                ->setAvailableLimit($page_size)
                ->setShowPerPage(true)
                ->setCollection($page_data);
            $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
            $this->getCustomData()->load();
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get pager HTML
     *
     * @return \VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\CustomPager
     */
    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }

    /**
     * Get custom data collection
     *
     * @return \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\CustomData
     */
    public function getCustomData()
    {
        $page = ($this->getRequest()->getParam('p')) ? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1;
        $pageSize = ($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit')) ? $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit') : 5;
        $collection = $this->customFactory->getCollection();
        $collection->setPageSize($pageSize);
        $collection->setCurPage($page);
        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * Get custom data collection
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getPagerCount()
    {
        $minimum_show = 5; // set minimum records
        $page_array = [];
        $list_data = $this->customdataCollection->create();
        $list_count = ceil(count($list_data->getData()));
        $show_count = $minimum_show + 1;
        if (count($list_data->getData()) >= $show_count) {
            $list_count = $list_count / $minimum_show;
            $page_nu = $total = $minimum_show;
            $page_array[$minimum_show] = $minimum_show;
            for ($x = 0; $x <= $list_count; $x++) {
                $total = $total + $page_nu;
                $page_array[$total] = $total;
            }
        } else {
            $page_array[$minimum_show] = $minimum_show;
            $minimum_show = $minimum_show + $minimum_show;
            $page_array[$minimum_show] = $minimum_show;
        }
        return $page_array;
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates**

**pager.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */
?>
<?php $custom_data = $block->getCustomData();?>
<?php if(!$block->getData('ajax_data')): ?>
<div class="custom-ajax-data">
<?php endif; ?>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <?php if(count($custom_data)): ?>
            <div class="table-wrapper custom-data ">
                <table class="data table table-data-items ">
                    <caption class="table-caption"><?= $block->escapeHtml('Custom Pagination') ?></caption>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col" class="col name"><?= $block->escapeHtml('Name') ?></th>
                            <th scope="col" class="col orders"><?= $block->escapeHtml('Email') ?></th>
                            <th scope="col" class="col orderitem"><?= $block->escapeHtml('Description') ?></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php foreach ($custom_data as $item): ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td data-th="Name" class="col name">
                             <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($item->getName()) ?></span>
                            </td>
                            <td data-th="Orders" class="col orders">
                                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($item->getEmail()) ?></span>
                            </td>
                            <td data-th="Items" class="col orderitem">
                                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($item->getDescription()) ?></span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
                    <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom">
                        <?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?>
                    </div>
            <?php endif ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <div class="message info empty">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml('You have no data in table.') ?></span>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php if(!$block->getData('ajax_data')): ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Block**

**CustomPager.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Block;

class CustomPager extends \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager
{
    /**
     * Current template name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_template = 'VendoreName_ModuleName::html/custompager.phtml';

    /**
     * Return page limit params
     *
     * @param int $limit
     * @return array
     */
    private function getPageLimitParams(int $limit): array
    {
        $data = [$this->getLimitVarName() => $limit];

        $currentPage = $this->getCurrentPage();
        $availableCount = (int) ceil($this->getTotalNum() / $limit);
        if ($currentPage !== 1 && $availableCount < $currentPage) {
            $data = array_merge($data, [$this->getPageVarName() => $availableCount === 1 ? null : $availableCount]);
        }

        return $data;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve page URL by defined parameters
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPagerUrl($params = [])
    {
        $urlParams = [];
        $urlParams['_current'] = true;
        $urlParams['_escape'] = true;
        $urlParams['_fragment'] = $this->getFragment();
        $urlParams['_query'] = $params;

        return $this->getUrl($this->getPath(), $urlParams);
    }

    /**
     * Get path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function getPath()
    {
        return "custom/index/ajaxdata";
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/templates/html**

**custompager.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */

/**
 * Pager template
 *
 * @see \VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\CustomPager
 */
?>
<?php if ($block->getCollection()->getSize()): ?>

    <?php if ($block->getUseContainer()): ?>
    <div class="pager">
    <?php endif ?>

        <?php if ($block->getShowAmounts()): ?>
        <p class="toolbar-amount">
            <span class="toolbar-number">
            <?php if ($block->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
                <?= $block->escapeHtml(
                    __('Items %1 to %2 of %3 total', $block->getFirstNum(), $block->getLastNum(), $block->getTotalNum())
                ) ?>
            <?php elseif ($block->getTotalNum() == 1): ?>
                <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('%1 Item', $block->getTotalNum())) ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('%1 Item(s)', $block->getTotalNum())) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </span>
        </p>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php if ($block->getLastPageNum()>1): ?>
        <div class="pages">
            <strong class="label pages-label" id="paging-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Page')) ?></strong>
            <ul class="items pages-items" aria-labelledby="paging-label">
            <?php if (!$block->isFirstPage()): ?>
                <li class="item pages-item-previous">
                    <?php $text = $block->getAnchorTextForPrevious() ? $block->getAnchorTextForPrevious() : '';?>
                    <a class="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($text ? 'link ' : 'action ') ?> previous ajax-page"
                       href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getPreviousPageUrl()) ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($text ? $text : __('Previous')) ?>">
                        <span class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Page')) ?></span>
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($text ? $text : __('Previous')) ?></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php if ($block->canShowFirst()): ?>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="page first ajax-page" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getFirstPageUrl()) ?>">
                        <span class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Page')) ?></span>
                        <span>1</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php if ($block->canShowPreviousJump()): ?>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="page previous jump ajax-page"
                       title=""
                       href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getPreviousJumpUrl()) ?>">
                        <span>...</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php foreach ($block->getFramePages() as $_page): ?>
                <?php if ($block->isPageCurrent($_page)): ?>
                    <li class="item current">
                        <strong class="page">
                            <span class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('You\'re currently reading page')) ?></span>
                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($_page) ?></span>
                        </strong>
                    </li>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <li class="item">
                        <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getPageUrl($_page)) ?>" class="ajax-page">
                            <span class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Page')) ?></span>
                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($_page) ?></span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <?php endif;?>
            <?php endforeach;?>

            <?php if ($block->canShowNextJump()): ?>
                <li class="item">
                    <a class="page next jump ajax-page" title="" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getNextJumpUrl()) ?>">
                        <span>...</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php if ($block->canShowLast()): ?>
              <li class="item">
                  <a class="page last ajax-page" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getLastPageUrl()) ?>">
                      <span class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Page')) ?></span>
                      <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getLastPageNum()) ?></span>
                  </a>
              </li>
            <?php endif;?>

            <?php if (!$block->isLastPage()): ?>
                <li class="item pages-item-next">
                    <?php $text = $block->getAnchorTextForNext() ? $block->getAnchorTextForNext() : '';?>
                    <a class="<?= /* @noEscape */ $text ? 'link ' : 'action ' ?> next ajax-page"
                       href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getNextPageUrl()) ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($text ? $text : __('Next')) ?>">
                        <span class="label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Page')) ?></span>
                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($text ? $text : __('Next')) ?></span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            <?php endif;?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if ($block->isShowPerPage()): ?>
        <div class="limiter">
            <strong class="limiter-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Show')) ?></strong>
            <?php /*<select id="limiter" data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl": {"event":"change"}}' class="limiter-options"> */ ?>
            <select id="limiter" class="limiter-options ajax-limiter-options">
                <?php foreach ($block->getAvailableLimit() as $_key => $_limit): ?>
                    <option value="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getLimitUrl($_key)) ?>"
                        <?php if ($block->isLimitCurrent($_key)): ?>
                        selected="selected"<?php endif ?>>
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_limit) ?>
                    </option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            <span class="limiter-text"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('per page')) ?></span>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <?php if ($block->getUseContainer()): ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif ?>

<?php endif ?>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Controller/Index**

**AjaxData.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * @category VendoreName ModuleName
 * @package VendoreName_ModuleName
 * @author Mahesh Makwana <maheshmakwana588@gmail.com>
 */

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class AjaxData extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $block = $resultPage->getLayout()
            ->createBlock(\VendoreName\ModuleName\Block\Pager::class)
            ->setData('ajax_data', true)
            ->setTemplate("VendoreName_ModuleName::pager.phtml");
        $resultJson = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_JSON);
        $data = ['content' => $block->toHtml()];
        $resultJson->setData($data);
        return $resultJson;
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js**

**ajax_pagination.js**

```
require(
    ["jquery"],
    function($){
    $(document).on('click', 'a.ajax-page', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('href'),
            type: 'POST',
            showLoader: true,
            success: function(response){
                $('.custom-ajax-data').html(response.content);
            }
        });
    });
    $(document).on('change', 'select.limiter-options.ajax-limiter-options', function(event){
        $.ajax({
            url: this.value,
            type: 'POST',
            showLoader: true,
            success: function(response){
                $('.custom-ajax-data').html(response.content);
            }
        });
    });
})
```

**[Click Here to Download](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HBdP5ml1C-JvDJ3l1g0Kz8WTB5CAx6vm?usp=sharing)**

***I Hope This Helps You.***